# Create multiple variables in data.table based other variables names

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, purrr

I am trying to create a series of variables, `c1, c2, and c3`, based on the values of two sets of variables, `a1, a2, and a3`, and `b1, b2, and b3`. The code below shows a hard-coded solution, but in reality I don't know the total number of set of variables, say `an` and `bn`. As you can see the name of the `c` variables depend on the names of the `a` and `b` variables.

Is there a way in `data.table` to do this? I tried to do it by using `purrr::map2` within `data.table` but I could not make it work.   I would highly appreciate your help.

Thanks.

```r
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
  a1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  a2 = c(1, 2, 3)*2,
  a3 = c(1, 2, 3)*3,
  b1 = c(5, 6, 7),
  b2 = c(5, 6, 7)*4,
  b3 = c(5, 6, 7)*5
)
DT[]
#>    a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3
#> 1:  1  2  3  5 20 25
#> 2:  2  4  6  6 24 30
#> 3:  3  6  9  7 28 35

DT[,
   `:=`(
     c1 = a1 + b1,
     c2 = a2 + b2,
     c3 = a3 + b3
   )
   ]
DT[]
#>    a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
#> 1:  1  2  3  5 20 25  6 22 28
#> 2:  2  4  6  6 24 30  8 28 36
#> 3:  3  6  9  7 28 35 10 34 44
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This first part is mostly defensive, guarding against: `a*` variables without matching `b*` variables; vice versa; and different order of each:

```r
anames <- grep("^a[0-9]+$", colnames(DT), value = TRUE)
bnames <- grep("^b[0-9]+$", colnames(DT), value = TRUE)
numnames <- gsub("^a", "", anames)
anames <- sort(anames[gsub("^a", "", anames) %in% numnames])
bnames <- sort(bnames[gsub("^b", "", bnames) %in% numnames])
cnames <- gsub("^b", "c", bnames)
```

If you know the number ranges a priori and want something less-dynamic but more straight-forward, then

```r
anames <- paste0("a", 1:3)
bnames <- paste0("b", 1:3)
cnames <- paste0("c", 1:3)
```

Now the magic:

```r
DT[, (cnames) := Map(`+`, mget(anames), mget(bnames)) ]
DT
#    a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
# 1:  1  2  3  5 20 25  6 22 28
# 2:  2  4  6  6 24 30  8 28 36
# 3:  3  6  9  7 28 35 10 34 44
```

Comment: In a similar vein: `DT[ , paste0("c", seq(ncol(DT)/2)) := Map(`+`, mget(ls(pattern = "a")), mget(ls(pattern = "b")))]`

Answer (score 4):

You could tackle this issue if you split `DT` column-wise by the pattern of the names first, and then aggregate it

```
# removes numbers from col names
(ptn <- sub("\\d", "", names(DT))) 
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"

# get unique numbers contained in the col names (as strings but it doesn't matter here)
(nmb <- unique(sub("\\D", "", names(DT))))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Next step is to split `DT` and finally do the aggregation

```
DT[, paste0("c", nmb) := do.call(`+`, split.default(DT, f = ptn))]
```

Result

```
DT
#   a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
#1:  1  2  3  5 20 25  6 22 28
#2:  2  4  6  6 24 30  8 28 36
#3:  3  6  9  7 28 35 10 34 44
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `melt` to long format, create the column 'c', `dcast` into 'wide' format and then `cbind`

```
library(data.table)
cbind(DT, dcast(melt(DT, measure = patterns('^a', '^b'))[,
    c := value1 + value2], rowid(variable) ~ paste0('c', variable),
        value.var = 'c')[, variable := NULL])
#   a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
#1:  1  2  3  5 20 25  6 22 28
#2:  2  4  6  6 24 30  8 28 36
#3:  3  6  9  7 28 35 10 34 44
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
u<-split.default(DT,gsub("\\D","",names(DT)))
cbind(DT,do.call(cbind,Map(rowSums,setNames(u,paste0("c",names(u))))))
```

which gives

```
   a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
1:  1  2  3  5 20 25  6 22 28
2:  2  4  6  6 24 30  8 28 36
3:  3  6  9  7 28 35 10 34 44
```